# Is "Top Posts" using the wrong active class?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

The active tab for the *Newest Posts* (user profile page, tab *"Profile"*, tab *"Newest"* and tab *"All"*) uses the class `active` which I think is not working. When referring to the *Answers* tab it uses the `youarehere` class.

---

> [image]
>
> [image]

---

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: The design issue is [around the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292754/) and [Hynes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292754/selected-tab-is-not-highlighted-in-the-profile-tab-questions-answers-section?noredirect=1#comment961877_292754) is looking on the issue.

Answer (score 13):

I reported this bug on [Meta Stack Exchage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292754/312043), and it has since been fixed.

The [response I got from Hynes (a Stack Overflow team member)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296454/312043) was:

> Thanks for reporting the issue (and sorry for taking 2 months to correct this!) This affected all community themes. It was caused from not applying the selected styles properly to `.active`. This has been corrected, as demonstrated here:
>
> [image]
>
> These changes will roll out to all other SE communities in the next production build.

Comment: Muh. _Testing?_ Maybe??